# android .mov format video playing from url

Tags: android, video

I am playing video from url then **.mp4** in playing but **.mov** format is giving `IOException`

```
java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
```

My code for playing video is,

```
private void playVideo() {
        if (extras.getString("video_path").equals("VIDEO_URI")) {
            showToast("Please, set the video URI in HelloAndroidActivity.java in onClick(View v) method");
        } else {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        player.setDataSource(extras.getString("video_path"));
                        player.setDisplay(holder);
                        player.prepare();
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                        showToast("Error while playing video");
                        Log.i(TAG, "========== IllegalArgumentException ===========");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        showToast("Error while playing video");
                        Log.i(TAG, "========== IllegalStateException ===========");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        showToast("Error while playing video. Please, check your network connection.");
                        Log.i(TAG, "========== IOException ===========");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }
```

Any pointers?

Comment: Can you please provide me with the URL you are trying to redirect

Comment: .mov does not support by android

Comment: android SDK supports  only .mp4 and .3gp video formats

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please visit the website [vitamio.org](http://vitamio.org) or download VitamioDemo from github [github.com/yixia/VitamioDemo](http://github.com/yixia/VitamioDemo)

if you want to use Vitamio as your video player in an app, you need to download the Vitamio SDK from their website. Play around with the demo project and you'll understand how it works.

I have implemented the same and it works absolutely fine with me.

Answer (score 0):

.mov files are not supported in android.

Check the [Supported Media Formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) on developers site.